# Why nltk word_tokenize is not working even after doing a nltk.download and all the packages are installed correctly?

Tags: python, nltk, python-3.7

I am using python 3.7 64 bit. nltk version 3.4.5.

When I try to convert text6 in nltk.book to tokens using word_tokenize, I am getting error.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.book import *
tokens=word_tokenize(text6)
```

code is done in idle 3.7

Below is the error when I execute the last statement.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    tokens=word_tokenize(text6)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 144, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 106, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1277, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1331, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1331, in <listcomp>
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1321, in span_tokenize
    for sl in slices:
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1362, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 318, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1335, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

While doing some troubleshooting I have created a sample nltk.text.Text object and tried to tokenize it with nltk.word_tokenize. Still I am getting the same error. Please see the below screenshot.[image]

But while calling the nltk.word_tokenize() on string, its working.

```
>>> tt="Python is a programming language"
>>> tokens2=nltk.word_tokenize(tt) #Not throwing error
>>> type(tt)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(text6)
<class 'nltk.text.Text'>
>>>
```

Comment: Your posted code does not define text6.  According to the exception, it must not be a string.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the `word_tokenize` function expects a string as its input. You're giving it a Book object. It seems like Book objects exposes an iterator that contains each word: `' '.join(text6)` might give you a string - but Book objects already have their tokenized versions available as `.tokens` (or `.token` if that doesn't work).

Comment: @TerryJanReedy It's from `from nltk.book import *` which imports all names in `nltk.book` into the current scope.

Comment: @MatsLindh, i have tried text6.tokens(). its giving me an error stating TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I am a c# developer and entirely new to python. I am just doing some analysis on nltk to learn natural language processing and python. Could you please help me resolve this error?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I have added some screenshots that will clarify the issue more. Please check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error is caused because you're calling it - i.e. you've added `()` after the list. The `.tokens` attribute is already a list - it's not a function that you call.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the nltk data folder. And where it expects it should be located.

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

nltk.download('punkt')

Comment: Please elaborate as to why you believe this solves the question at hand, provide some additional code to provide some context.

Comment: 'punkt' is a sentence tokenizer that divides a text into a list of sentences. Sometimes word_tokenize function will not work on large collection of plain text for which downloading punkt module can be useful. 
You can download punkt module before importing word_tokenize:
Eg:

> nltk.download('punkt')
> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize